# How can I fix this exception? i'm not able to find who generate this

Tags: c#, visual-studio

after a long time that I run my app on degugger i read this exception on the Application.Run line code. I'm not able to fix the source of this exception so in alternative how can i catch it? 
i didn't find any information on the exception details.. it's a mistake for me!

```
'BinsTrackerApofruit.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: BinsTrackerApofruit.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Transactions.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_it_b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.resources.dll' completato. Modulo compilato senza simboli.
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Eccezione non gestita</Description><AppDomain>BinsTrackerApofruit.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Index non compreso nell'intervallo. Richiesto valore non negativo e minore della dimensione della raccolta.
Nome parametro: index</Message><StackTrace>   in System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   in System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   in System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message&amp;amp; m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index non compreso nell'intervallo. Richiesto valore non negativo e minore della dimensione della raccolta.
Nome parametro: index
   in System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   in System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   in System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message&amp;amp; m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
Eccezione non gestita di tipo 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in mscorlib.dll
Index non compreso nell'intervallo. Richiesto valore non negativo e minore della dimensione della raccolta.`
```

I use a spashscreen class for run my app:

```
public static class Program
{
    private static bool _metextry;

    /// <summary>
    /// Indica se il programma deve uscite
    /// </summary>
    public static bool ForceExit;

    private static Mutex mutex = null;
    internal static Form_Container MyContainer { get; set; }
    internal static SplashViewer splash { get; set; }

    [STAThread]
    public  static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        const string appName = "BinsTracker_V7";

        bool createdNew;

        mutex = new Mutex(true, appName, out createdNew);

        if (!createdNew)
        {
            _metextry = true;

            MyMessageBox.Show("E' possibile avviare una sola istanza dell'applicazione.", "");
            return;
        }
        ;
        MyContainer = new Form_Container();

        splash = new SplashViewer();

        splash.Run(new string[] { });

    }
}
```

the spash look likes:

```
class SplashViewer : Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{

    protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
    {
        Tracker.Inizializza();
        Tracker.Avvia(); // this method run my app 
        this.MainForm = Program.MyContainer;
    }

    protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen()
    {
        this.SplashScreen = new InitialSplashScreen();

    }
    protected override bool OnInitialize(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> commandLineArgs)
    {
        // Si visualizza per 3 secondi
        this.MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime = 3000;
        return base.OnInitialize(commandLineArgs);
    }

}


}
```

Who's the form that generate this ?? how can i find the source?? 
Thank's everyone for the support!

Comment: What is `Form_Container`? According to the code you provided, the problem you encountered cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Form_Container is a simple Form with MdiContainer property  and 2 toolstrips.

Comment: I can post the code if you think it can generate the problem.